How to pass array from one file to yaml file
Lets say I have this array:
[ 'value1','value2','value3' ]

I want to pass into my yaml file this array from another file.
my yaml should accept array in this field:
parameters: 
  arrayExpected: arrayValueFromAnotherFile

I could have simply this:
parameters:  
  arrayExpected: [ 'value1','value2','value3' ]

But for specific reasons this is not good approach in my situation. As yaml file cant get very overpopulated with array values.
So far I know that yaml has no imports statements available, perhaps anyone had similar issue and resolved it ?

What exactly are you planning to do with that array? Maybe instead of the array you can have a filePath parameter and use a script task to parse the file in json format (or other)?

And what exactly do you mean by another file? A pipeline template or...?

array will be itared with foreach on yaml side and then each array value will be used in further script js.
And yeah it can be another yaml file, or whatever as long as I can import values from another file into current yaml

@DanieliusPolujanskis, parameters are expanded before pipeline runs. If you would like to pass the value from yaml, you need to use another pipeline to get the value and pass value to target pipeline. Please check the answer below, let me know if you have any queries.


I want to pass into my yaml file this array from another file.

You can use another pipeline to get the array from the file, then transfer the parameter value to target pipeline via rest api Runs - Run Pipeline with templateParameters to set the parameters.
For example, array in array.txt:

The 1st pipeline sample, please change the target pipeline definition id to yours.
trigger: none

pool:
  vmImage: Windows-latest

steps:
- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      $array = Get-Content array.txt
      $array = $array.TrimStart("[").TrimEnd("]") 
      Write-Output $array        # check the string content
      $body = @"
      { 
              "definition": {
                  "id": 565              # your target pipeline definition id
              },
              "templateParameters": {
                "arrayExpected": "$array"
             }
      }
      "@
      $Uri = "$(System.CollectionUri)$(System.TeamProject)/_apis/build/builds?api-version=7.1-preview.7"
      Write-Host $Uri
      $buildresponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -ContentType "application/json" -Uri $Uri -Body $body -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $(System.AccessToken)"}
      write-host $buildresponse

The target pipeline sample:
trigger: none

parameters:  
- name: arrayExpected
  type: string
  default: ""

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- script: echo ${{ parameters.arrayExpected }}

- ${{ each value in split(parameters.arrayExpected, ',')}}:
  - script: echo ${{ value }}
    displayName: 'check value'


I used $(system.accesstoken) to trigger the target pipeline, please make sure build service account has permission on the target pipeline.

